# error during installation of gnome tweaks

Tags: gnome, gnome-tweak-tool

I tried installing gnome tweaks 
i first `sudo apt update` and then this

```
E: Unable to locate package gnome-tweaks
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks;
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gnome-tweaks
```

Comment: What command did you type? Did you try installing it from the Ubuntu Software Center?

Comment: you need universe in your package source. and the package name is gnome-tweak-tool.

Comment: A quick search with `apt-cache` returns that there is a package named `gnome-tweaks - tool to adjust advanced configuration settings for GNOME`. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.